# upload a picture PHP (failing)

Tags: php, image, apache, upload

I'm trying to build a form to upload a thumbnail (image) to the server - looks like the image is successfully uploading to the servers temp folder (I've confirmed this with `get_defined_vars` - its giving a temp file name and no errors), but its not being moved to the folder in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

The end goal here is to get the image uploaded then return a url to be stored in MySQL

HTML Form (located in DOCUMENT_ROOT/admin)

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="thumbnail">Thumbnail </label>
  <input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail">
</form>
```

Upload.php

```
<?php
$thumbnail = uploadfile($_FILE['thumbnail']['name'],$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/thumbs/upload/',$_FILE['thumbnail']['tmp_name']);
if(($thumbnail)!== FALSE)
{echo $thumbnail;} else {echo 'upload failed<br>';}

function uploadfile($origin, $dest, $tmp_name)
{
  $origin = strtolower(basename($origin));
  $fulldest = $dest.$origin;
  $filename = $origin;
  echo '$fulldest '.$fulldest.'<br />';
  echo '$filename '.$filename.'<br />';
  if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $fulldest))
    {return $filename;}
  return false;
}
?>
```

result (note: I've removed the actual document root)

```
$fulldest [DOCUMENT_ROOT] /thumbs/upload/
$filename 
upload failed
```

I've also set an .htaccess directive for upload 500M to make sure image size isn't the problem

```
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value upload_max_filesize 500M
  php_value post_max_size 500M
</IfModule>
```

EDIT:: My target directory is chmod 0777 for testing - so permissions shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: could be a permission issue on the destination directory

Comment: The user you are running your web server as will need write access to the target directory. Check your permissions.

Comment: my directory is 0777, updated original  post to include this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help noticing that your `$filename` is empty and `$fulldest` lack the filename. I think the problem is that you use `$_FILE` and not `$_FILES`.

```
$thumbnail = uploadfile($_FILES['thumbnail']['name'],
             $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/thumbs/upload/',
             $_FILES['thumbnail']['tmp_name']);
```

I think that would work.

Comment: yup - its $_FILES not $FILE ... Thanks! @Qben solved my problem

(@Qben please edit your answer for others benefit, your missing a ] in the first permitter )